# UITextView, how do I remove the return key:linefeed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I want to remove the linefeed that was entered in by the return key.  But when I do the following it remove the last character from the text. Why?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    NSLog(@"%d  %d  %@ %@",range.location,range.length, text, [textView text]);

    if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {

        NSString *s = [textView text];
        s = [s substringToIndex:[s length] - 1]; // <------------

        [tvText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n>>",s]];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

---

I want the result to look like:

```
>>name
>>yoda
>>                <---- cursor is moved to the right of ">>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do something like this,

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    NSLog(@"%d  %d  %@ %@",range.location,range.length, text, [textView text]);

    if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {

        [tvText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n>>",tvText.text]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe after your reading string in line and put it to some substring:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n;" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3):

shouldChangeTextInRange is part of the [UITextViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html), and is called **before** the new text is changed in the textView. Therefore, you could just do this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: By far the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this for better solution as it won't allow user to post any blank message in any case.

```
//These for loops will remove the spaces and new line characters from start and end of the string

    //&&//

    NSMutableString *temp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:posttextview.text];

    //Remove spaces and new line characters from start
    for(int i = 0; i < yourtext.length; i++)
    {
        NSString *temp1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[temp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)]];

        if([temp1 isEqualToString:@"\n"] || [temp1 isEqualToString:@" "])
        {
            [temp deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    yourtext.text = temp;

    //Remove spaces and new line characters from end
    for(int i = 0; i < yourtext.length; i++)
    {
        NSString *temp1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[temp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(posttextview.text.length - 1,1)]];

        if([temp1 isEqualToString:@"\n"] || [temp1 isEqualToString:@" "])
        {
            [temp deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(posttextview.text.length - 1,1)];

            yourtext.text = temp;
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    yourtext.text = temp;

    //**//
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the time shouldChangeCharactersImRange is called, the new text is not actually changed yet (that's why it's not named didChangeCharactersInRange...). So in case you encounter a newline, don't trick with the substrings, just store/process the string the text view contains so far, and return NO.

Answer (score 0):

First add the UITextViewDelegate in your .h file

```
@interface YourClass : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}
```

then implement the delegate method

```
-(BOOL)shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```